# Windows 10: How to make File downloaded to Desktop appears as last

Tags: windows-10, desktop

When I download a file and set the destination to my Desktop, the file appears before all my shortcuts, even before "This PC". I want the file to appear as the last icon. Any tips?

Comment: Sort your desktop icons by `date modified`

Comment: Rename the file "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want the file to appear as the last icon. Any tips?

**Solution 1:**

- Right click on Desktop > Select "Sort by" > Select "Date modified"

[image]

**Solution 2:**

- Right click on Desktop > Select "Sort by" > Select "Name"
- Rename the file "ZZZZZZZZZ"

Comment: Worked, although not very untuitively designed. On the one hand its sorted, on the other hand I can rearange the Desktop icons.

Comment: @cypressious Right click > "View" > "Auto arrange icons" prevents rearranging.